# Where is the Assembly.cs file in a VS2005 Website project?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, log4net

I am trying to add some assembly info for log4net so that it can have a file watcher. It appears that the website project does not have this file. Does this mean that I am doomed to use the web.config file and that I cannot split out log4net's config and use a file wathcer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file is created for a Web Application project, and not for a web site project.

[Comparing Web Site Projects and Web Application Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730880%28VS.80%29.aspx#wapp_topic5)

Comment: So then, what about the second part of my question? How can I get log4net to use its own config file and use a file watcher?